# Extend the function sinus by enlarging the upper and lower curve?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, trigonometry

I need for computer science to recreate the movement of a bird(the wings go down and up periodically). For this I am using the function sin(x), the problem is that when wings reaches the upper/lower limits(reaching 1/-1) -> the bird's wings should slow down and on other hand, increase in speed by going through the upper limit to the lower one.

This is what is sinx:
[sinx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMO2K.png)

And this is what I want to achieve(something like this):
[something like this to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJiWG.png)

Is there a mathematical aproach if so from what I should start, I am not very good in math but I really need help.

Comment: Choose any function on $[-1,1]$ that is odd, increasing, and whose slope decreases away from zero, for example $f(y) = 1.5y - 0.5y^3$, and use $f(\sin(x))$. Simple Art's solution corresponds to choosing $f(y) = \operatorname{sgn}(y)\sqrt{|y|}$.

Comment: I have one question what was your approach to finding this solution also, like how you figured out that this is the function that suits to this case(or you guessed it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "square-ify" the curve, you could try the following:

$$y=\sqrt{|\sin(x)|}$$

Or if that's not enough,

$$y=\sqrt[n]{|\sin(x)|}$$

For some $n$.  Then, of course, adjust the sign of the graph to make it do the wavy thing using

$$y=\operatorname{sgn}[\sin(x)]\sqrt[n]{|\sin(x)|}$$

where $\operatorname{sgn}$  returns $+1$ or $-1$ depending on the sign of the sine.

Comment: this is what I was searching, thank you very much, the answer will accepted as soon as possible

Comment: @DomainFlag No problem.  Cheers.